# Entity Framework 4 -- Problems with ExecuteFunction<T> of FunctionImport mapped to POCO Complex Type

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, poco

I am receiving an error when trying to execute a `FunctionImport` -- result is mapped to a POCO ComplexType -- from within a custom `ObjectContext`.  Specifically, the error states:

> The type parameter `BlahComplexType` in ExecuteFunction is incompatible with the type `BlahComplexType` returned by the function.

Because I'm using a custom `ObjectContext` (I'm working with a fully POCO Entity Framework environment), I must call the `FunctionImport` manually, which I do like:

```
var blah = ExecuteFunction<BlahComplexType>("GetBlah", MergeOption.NoTracking,
            new ObjectParameter("p_one", paramOne),
            new ObjectParameter("p_two", paramTwo),
            new ObjectParameter("p_three", string.Empty));
```

I am not using any T4 templates to generate POCOs, all classes are manually written.  `BlahComplexType` is a class with simple data type properties.  Its definition matches the ComplexType definition in the .edmx file, including matching namespaces and everything (I've got plenty of other Entities and Complex Types mapped to POCOs, as well).

The msdn documentation states [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd779947.aspx) that the return type of `ExecuteFunction<T>` must implement `IEntityWithChangeTracker`, but isn't the whole point of mapping to a ComplexType instead of an Entity is precisely because I don't care about any changes (in fact, changes are not allowed -- BlahComplexType is considered a "Value Object")?

**Has anyone had any luck calling a FunctionImport with ExecuteFunction whose results are mapped to a POCO ComplexType with Entity Framework 4?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wow, stupid user error!!

As always with manual creation of the POCO classes -- it was an inconsistency between the ComplexType definition in the EDMX file and its POCO class.  If there's just one error or inconsistency, then the error message makes an attempt at telling you the source of the problem.  However, if you have more than one, it'll just state that the types are "incompatible", so you're left wondering.

In my case, I had both a property name inconsistency (one had "AcctId", the other had "Acctid") and a property data inconsistency (class was expecting int (Int32) but the stored procedure returned Int16).

So, as always, double and triple check EDMX definition and POCO class definition.  (I double checked, but neglected to triple check!!)

*facepalm*